# Go XML marshalling without encoding HTML entities

Tags: xml, go

I'd like to marshal a struct into XML, but without encoding special HTML-entities. See this example:

http://play.golang.org/p/7NOhOTwlHr

The string `test&abc` gets converted to `test&amp;abc`, but I'd like it to stay `test&abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand is escaped using the rules in the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/). It is not possible to disable escaping in the output of the standard encoding/xml package.

(Ampersand escaping in HTML and XML shares a common heritage from SGML, but each is specified separately. One does not derive from or reference the other).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the tag ",innerxml" as show in the example. [Here](http://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/07.1.html) it explains that ",innerxml" makes unmarshal "assign raw XML data to it". But it also work well with Marshal avoiding the string formating.

http://play.golang.org/p/z8JQjRdbV4

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
 data, err = xml.Marshal(toMarshal)
 data = bytes.Replace(data, []byte("&amp;"), []byte("&"), -1)
 fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Also you can use `&gt; &lt;` ,...